# React is rendering a 0 when condition fails

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting a 0 being rendered on the page when showScore is false

```js
<div>
   { !isObjectEmpty(userReport) &&
     <div className={'data'}>
       {showScore && <span><FaTrophy/> {score}</span>}
     </div>
   }
</div>
```

CSS for this div

```css
padding: 10px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

Any ideas why I would get a 0 in the page instead of **nothing** when showScore is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're trying to display **nothing** instead of a `0`, you might try this:

```js
{ showScore ? (<span><FaTrophy/> {score}</span>) : '' }
```